# How to programmatically launch iOS Safari and search with default engine (iOS 14.x)?

Tags: ios, url, search, safari

Per the title. How do you programmatically launch iOS Safari from an app, and search with the default engine in iOS 14.x?

Found solutions to pass an NSURL of "x-web-search://?somekeyword" to UIApplication:openURL, but this is currently not working.

Would like to use (and respect) the user's settings, and not hard-code a search engine URL.